# Not updating QLabel value

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I would like to read a data file and print the size of the data using QLabel. I can only call setText before reading the data so it returns 0 and does not change after I read the data. Can you please help me with how I can update the value of Qlabel once the data read?

```
MainInterfaceWindow::MainInterfaceWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainInterfaceWindow){
  ui->label->setText(QString::number(ui->openGLWidget->m_size));
 }

void Canvas::DoDataRelatedStuff{
     ...
     m_size= dataSize.size();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a signal to your canvas class

```
// Canvas.h
class Canvas : public /* base class */ {
    // required in header
    Q_OBJECT 

// ... other class stuff ...

signals:
   void dataSizeChanged(int size);

}
```

In your MainInterfaceWindow, connect that signal to a lambda function that updates the text:

```
MainInterfaceWindow::MainInterfaceWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainInterfaceWindow){
  ui->label->setText(QString::number(ui->openGLWidget->m_size));

  connect(ui->openGLWidget, &Canvas::dataSizeChanged, ui->label, 
    [](auto size){ ui->label->setText(QString::number(size)); });
 }
```